# EagleCad Warning errors

Tags: eaglecad, cad

Is it normal for me to be getting these warnings when I changed the names of the wires? 
[image: ERC warning]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it appears that a pin on many of your parts is designated to be a POWER connection. This means that Eagle expects that pin to be connected to a Vcc from the supply1 or supply2 library.

If you are connecting power manually using a net not connected to Vcc, then Eagle will give you these errors as the expected POWER connection is not present.

It's just a safety check. In industry you would probably want to designate things properly and connect things according to specifications. In my board I sometimes have nets named 5V, 12V, etc.. and sometimes get these errors as the ICs are not connected to a Vcc (strictly speaking).

Comment: Except it does not make sense to connect power to 7 segment driver output. Looks like a poorly made symbol to me.

Comment: "Eagle expects that pin to be connected to a Vcc from the supply1 or supply2 library" - there isn't anything special about those two libraries. Eagle is expecting power pins to be connected to a net with the same name as the pin (e.g. if the power pin is called Vcc, it expects it to be on a net called Vcc). Those sorts of warnings should be simply checked through (make sure the power pins are on the right nets) and approved.

Answer (score 0):

Basically pins in eagle schematic symbols can have different types (e.g. Input [`in`], Output [`out`], Power [`pwr`], etc.).

Any pin that has a type of Power, Eagle is expecting to be connected to a net with the same name as the pin (e.g. if the power pin is called Vcc, it expects it to be on a net called Vcc). If it is not, you will get a warning to let you know. These should be simply checked through (make sure the power pins are on the right nets) and approved.

**However**, `power` pins should only be used for power connections (e.g. VCC, GND, 5V, etc.). The fact that you are getting these warnings for the pins of your 7-segment display means that the symbol was not made correctly. Personally, I would edit the symbol and change the type to either passive [`pas`] or bidirectional [`io`].